# Best way to check if user has two instances of website running

Tags: php, session

I have some ideas about it but very basic and not complete. I wonder what is the best way to check if same PC/IP is logged with two different users and runs two instances of my website?

Comment: There is no sure-fire way to do this, because multiple PCs could be behind a router. What do you need this for?

Comment: Well I just want to know, It's not like it's some kind of serious threat, just be good to have some basic protection against it.

Comment: there is no possible way to detect "the same" PC.

Comment: Against what? You said it is not serious (actually it is not threat at all).

Comment: Well for example if I don't want user in my Admin panel to open two instances of it in different tabs/browsers. Maybe not PC, but IP then...

Comment: @Qmal: why don't you want it? Any reason?

Comment: If they are logged in then just limit the number of logins for that same user.

Comment: For this purpose, you might just check for duplicate sessions after authentication. If it is the same authenticated system user, then you can terminate the other session. "Same PC" with different authenticated users should be allowed/cannot be defended against.

Comment: This discussion becomes absolutely useless. Guys, there is no reason to implement such limitations. Just get that it is not what you need. You still have a lot of places in your project that can be reimplemented in better way, and avoid-to-login-from-the-same-PC is not one of them

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If two users have the same IP, they are either

- on the same computer
- in the same household, office or company with a shared internet connection
- in the same Internet café

this is as far as you can get. Reliably detecting whether two sessions are on the same *computer* is close to impossible, as there is no metric that could help you tell.

If you want to battle fraud, you will need to use different methods.

Comment: Considering that I can use different connections from the same computer, not even that is absolutely true.

Comment: For http it is not possible at all (if we don't use ActiveX and read some sort of hardware ids, but even in this case user can just start another session in virtual machine).

Answer (score 1):

**First**, let the server send a unique token (e.g. [csrf token](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Cross-Site_Request_Forgery_%28CSRF%29_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet)) when the page loads and each time the user interacts. Then, let each user interaction (post or request) include this token (and generate a new one).

When you get unexpected tokens from the same IP adress, you apply a **second** trick: add the mousevent timestamps to the request and log (to the millisecond) the time differences (henceforth **dt**) between the local server time and the timestamp that came with the token, with a certain error margin for the variation in delaytime.

In the case two instances are running on the same PC, **dt** will be equal for both unique tokens (that were generated during the most recent interaction or pageloading).

On another physical computer, the chance that the **dt** is the same (even within the error margin) as on another pc on the same IP adress is extremely small, so that you have a valid way of testing.

Comment: +1 for creativity. I'm not so sure about reliability or even correctness, but the innovation has to be commended

Comment: perhaps if javascript allowed passing of the CPUtime rather than the system time it would be more reliable, but for @Pekka 's mentioning of pc's using the same IP in the same household, office or company or pc's in the same Internet café, it could actually do the trick. Anyway, thanks for the 16% upgrade of my 'reputation'!

Answer (score 0):

you can check the ip-address, user-agent, time-zone, activated plugins...
To avoid more than one users logged in from the same computer you can set cookies or transmit a session key on every link. (you have to combine the hash with the ip-address an user-information you get because of copying the link should not log in other users into the account the hash belongs to)